# Unable to ammend an XML value in Grails

Tags: xml, grails, xmlslurper

I'm using Grails 2.5.6 and OpenJDK1.8.0.292.

I'm trying to download an XML file from a TFTP server, ammend one of the node values, and then write the ammended file locally. My code looks like :-

```
def xmlFile = simpleSftpService.downloadFile('tftp_file.xml')

def DeviceSettings = new XmlSlurper().parse(xmlFile)
println "Current IP Address = " + DeviceSettings.Network.IpAddress.text()

DeviceSettings.Network.IpAddress.value = "192.168.1.20"

def writer = new FileWriter('ammended_file.xml')
    def builder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
    writer << builder.bind {
        mkp.yield DeviceSettings
    }
```

This all runs through quite happily, and the output of println shows an IP address of 192.168.1.10, but the ammended_file.xml that is written also has a value of 192.168.1.10 for the IpAddress node, which is what it was originally set to in the tftp_file.xml, rather than the new value of 192.168.1.20

My XML file looks something like (I've left out all the rest of the XML which is, I think, irrelevant) :-

```
<DeviceSettings>
    <Network>
        <IpAddress>192.168.1.10</IpAddress>
    </Network>
</DeviceSettings>
```

I'm certain I'm getting confused with how you can change or ammend a value in the XML so any pointers as to how I should do this would be greatfully received.

Answer (score 0):

So, I discovered that I needed to use the .each function to make this work. So instead of simply doing this :-

```
DeviceSettings.Network.IpAddress.value = "192.168.1.20"
```

I now do this, which seems to work  :-

```
DeviceSettings.Network.each{
        it.'IpAddress' = "192.168.1.20"
    }
```

I'm not entirely clear why this is, so any explanations would be gratefully received.